# How do I collapse the rest of the section when one section is expanded after click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these two sections. When I click the arrow button, it will collapse or expand. How do I force other sections to collapse when one section expand after click?

```css
        @media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {            
            #resume {
                width: 820px;
                margin: 2rem auto;

            }

            .toggle-item {
                transform: translate(-9999px);
            }

                .toggle-item + label {
                    display: block;
                    margin-top: -16px;
                }

                .toggle-item:checked + label:after {
                    content: '\f0d7';
                }

                .toggle-item + label:after {
                    float: left;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    margin-left: -20px;
                    color: #aaa;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    content: '\f0da';
                    font-family: Fontawesome;
                }

                .toggle-item ~ .item {
                    height: 0;
                    opacity: 0;
                }

                .toggle-item:checked ~ .item {
                    height: auto;
                    opacity: 1;
                    transition: all .5s linear;
                }            
        }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="resume">
        <section class="section">          
          <section id="work">
            <section class="work-item">
              <input id="work-item-0" type="checkbox" class="toggle-item" checked="checked" />
              <label for="work-item-0"></label>
              <header>
                <div class="position">
                  Joe
                </div>
              </header>
              <div class="item" id="work-item">
                <div class="summary">
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
          </section>
          <section id="work">
            <section class="work-item">
              <input id="work-item-0.5" type="checkbox" class="toggle-item" checked="checked" />
              <label for="work-item-0.5"></label>
              <header>
                <div class="position">Doe</div>                
              </header>
              <div class="item" id="work-item">
                <div class="summary">
                  <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
          </section>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a simple solution, you could use an input of type radio instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="resume">
    <section class="section">          
      <section id="work">
        <section class="work-item">
          <input id="work-item-0" type="radio" class="toggle-item" value="2" name="a" />
          <label for="work-item-0"></label>
          <header>
            <div class="position">
              Joe
            </div>
          </header>
          <div class="item" id="work-item">
            <div class="summary">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </section>
      <section id="work">
        <section class="work-item">
          <input id="work-item-0.5" type="radio" class="toggle-item" value="1" name="a" />
          <label for="work-item-0.5"></label>
          <header>
            <div class="position">Doe</div>                
          </header>
          <div class="item" id="work-item">
            <div class="summary">
              <p>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </section>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But neither checkboxes nor radio buttons are meant for this kind of logic and this solution is not good with respect to maintainability, as even small changes to your html can break it.

As a clean solution I would recommend to write a JavaScript that assigns CSS classes dynamically to your sections in response to click events.

Comment: When I click the arrow, it expands but when I click the same arrow, it doesn't collapse back.